# cl.exe in cygwin shell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, cygwin

I have a host system and a virtual machine and i am trying to setup similar environment in both.
I installed cygwin and visual studio 10 also.
I faced issues in my build and I finally managed to find one difference between my host and vm.

in my host when in cygwin shell when i enter cl I get the following:

```
$ cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
```

But in my vm I am getting no output.

```
$ cl
```

(VM is 32 bit and host is 64 bit)

Can someone tell me what setting I might have missed out on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you should do is to find out what `cl` *is* within the CygWin where it's not working. Execute the commands:

```
typeset -f cl
which cl
alias cl
```

and find out what it comes back with. If it's anything other than the MS compiler, that's your problem.

Beyond that, find out what the erroneous environment does when you try to run `cl` from a `cmd` window rather than CygWin `bash`.

---

Based on your comment:

> On my VM, it is:
>   `$ which cl
>   /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl`

This is definitely wrong for a 32-bit VM. You are attempting to use the 64-bit AMD compiler on a system that doesn't support it.

You should change the path to use a 32-bit compiler. However, I'm not sure you have one since all of `amd64`, `ia64`, `x86_amd64` and `x86_ia64` seem to indicate 64-bit compilers.

The one directly under `bin` may be okay, you would have to test it to be certain (possibly with `dumpbin` which should be able to tell you the file format of the executable).

Comment: my host its $ which cl
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl and in my vm it is $ which cl
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl

Comment: alias returned $ alias cl
bash: alias: cl: not found

Comment: typeset -f cl - this also does not return anything

Comment: @newbie, that second/third comment's okay. It may be neither an alias nor a function, in which case `which` will be the controlling factor.

Comment: Just a quick clarification - my processor is intel i7 and when setting the path to visual studio 10/bin, there are four folders under bin amd64,ia64,x86_amd64 and x86_ia64 and there are cl.exe files under all of them. also there is a cl.exe file right under the bin folder. so which one should be set .. is it either the cl.exe present directly under bin folder or the one under the x86 folder?

Comment: yes that was the error,i had set the wrong path, now it is working.